# Prove BA is not invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

I have seen this exercise here but I think I solved it with details. The exercise states:

Let A: $\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ and B: $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ be linear transformations, so BA: $\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$

Prove that BA cannot be invertible.

Proof: First, recall that $$rank(BA) \leq \min(Rank(A),Rank(B))\leq rank(A) \leq 2.$$

If we suppose that BA is invertible then $Nullity(BA)=0$ and

$$3=dim(\mathbb{R}^3)=Nullity(BA)+rank(BA) \leq 2,$$
but this is a contradiction. Hence $BA$ is not invertible.

Q.E.D.

Is it my argument right or well written?

Comment: Why do you say $\min(Rank(A),Rank(B))=rank(A)\;$?

Comment: $Rank(B) \leq 3$ and $Rank(A) \leq 2$ so the minimum must be $Rank(A)$, I think is wrong maybe I have to put only the inequality right?

Comment: @Bayesianguy It could be $\mathrm{rank}(B) = 1, \mathrm{rank}(A) = 2$.

Comment: It is a minor point. I think the following is correct: $ \min(Rank(A),Rank(B))\le rank(A) \leq 2.$

Comment: Yes, let me edit it. Anyway, my proof is right?

Comment: Why are you bothering with the nullity? And why are you bothering with an argument by contradiction? If the matrix is not full rank, then it is certainly not invertible. The rank of $BA$ is less than $3$, so the range is not all of $\mathbb{R}^3$: the map is not surjective.

Comment: Yes, is another approach. Thanks

Comment: The point is that you shouldn't scratch your left ear by draping your right hand over your head in order to reach it: you should just use your left hand. Russian “Zachem tak slozhnu?” Means: “Why so complicated?” How to do it: reach behind head and scratch left ear with right hand or vice versa – means that something has been expressed backwards or has been made too complicated. [See illustration](https://i.guim.co.uk/img/static/sys-images/Guardian/Pix/pictures/2010/1/28/1264687932090/too-complicated-002.jpg?width=1010&quality=85&auto=format&fit=max&s=72989f5f816d1cfc6247de50039a554b).

Comment: Indeed. In fact, that's why I post my problems here, to improve my skills. Now with another similar problem, I would use your argument. Many thanks.